# Входящие ссылки на сайт

Tags: seo, маркетинг

Всем привет! Я не являюсь seo специалистом, но нужно немного продвинуть 1 сайт. Насколько я знаю главным фактором является кол-во входящих ссылок на сайт. Подскажете на каких сайтах можно зарегистрироваться чтобы получить минимальный рейтинг. Как мне говорили очень хорошее влияние оказывал на продвижение  сайт dmoz, но его закрыли.

Вот то что написано в личном кабинете яндекс вебмастер:
тИЦ определяет «авторитетность» сайта с учетом качества ссылок на него с других сайтов. Отсюда можно сделать вывод что входящие ссылки играют важную роль.

Comment: Главных факторов, насколько мне известно, огромное множество. Это и оригинальность, ключевые слова, скорость загрузки, мобильная версия сайта и т.д. Разве количество ссылок на страницу влияет на ранжирование в поисковиках?

Comment: постоянно растущий контент есть и сайт имеет нужную структуру, смотрите я дописал вопрос

Comment: Вот, как раз, Яндекс очень старательно борется за чистоту ссылок. Ссылки должны быть, но должны быть "натуральные". И почитайте у Яндекса, как влияет тиц на "выдачу". Тиц используется для: тИЦ как средство определения авторитетности ресурсов призван обеспечить релевантность расположения ресурсов в рубриках каталога Яндекса. Напрямую на поисковую выдачу он не влияет, но влияют входящие ссылки, но только хорошие, тематические ссылки, да и то, это не самый главный фактор. Почитайте про "Минусинск" в блогах Яндекса и на Серче.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что когда еще существовал каталог dmoz, успешная регистрация в нем не оказывала никакого положительного воздействия на продвижение сайта ?

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки уже давно не играют первостепенную роль для ранжирования сайтов. Ссылки полезны там, где их может увидеть пользователь, заинтересоваться и перейти на Ваш сайт. Если Ваш сайт качественный, то это оценят и пользователи и поисковые системы. Не надо стараться закупить/налепить ссылок по всему интернету. Смотрите первые сайты с поисковой выдачи по нужным вам запросам, ищите каталоги/справочники/отзовики и пытайтесь добавить информацию о своем сайте к ним. Если варианты и бесплатные и платные. Получите и плюсики от ПС и качественный трафик.

Comment: я дописал вопрос, как я понял ссылки играют очень важную роль